# Batch resize images in Mac OS X without changing the creation date

Tags: macos

I have a lot of images to resize, but I don’t want to change the creation date. I tried to use Automator, Photoshop, Preview and every time I use this, the software changes the creation date of my pictures.

If someone have an idea?

Comment: The “real” creation date (in EXIF metadata) should never change. You can’t rely on filesystem metadata for stuff like that anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a lot of images to resize, but I don’t want to change the
>   creation date. I tried to use Automator, Photoshop, Preview and every
>   time I use this, the software changes the creation date of my
>   pictures.

Are you mixing up creation date with the modification date? Because ultimately, the creation date of a file should never change if a file is modified; that is what the modification date is for.

While I am unsure what methods you are using to resize the images, from what I know if you are taking a directory of images—and then telling a script to create a derivative image based on the source image—the newly created derivative image would have a new creation date because it would simply be a new copy of the original that is processed in some way.

But assuming you have a directory filled with images you want to process and—essentially—overwrite, I would recommend installing and using the excellent command line tool [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). If you are not comfortable installing ImageMagick for Mac OS X via the official binaries—which work well, but can be confusing if you are not fluent doing command line stuff—this [nice Mac OS X package installer exists is provided by Cactuslab](http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick/). Or you can even install ImageMagick via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) by installing it and then running `brew install imagemagick` from the command line to install ImageMagick.

Once installed, you can run a simple Bash script like this that uses [`find`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html) with the ImageMagick [`convert`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) command tool to process the images:

```
find -E 'Desktop/Pics' -type f -iregex '.*\.(JPG|JPEG|PNG|TIF|TIFF)$' |\
  while read FULL_IMAGE_PATH
  do
    convert -density 72 -units PixelsPerInch -resize "1500x1500>" -quality 90 "${FULL_IMAGE_PATH}" "${FULL_IMAGE_PATH}"
  done
```

In this example, the script will look for the `Pics/` directory on your working user’s desktop and then search for any files within `Pics/` that have an extension of JPG, JPEG, PNG, TIF or TIFF connected to them; the search is case insensitive so lowercase versions will be found as well. Once an image is found it will convert the DPI of the image to 72 and do it using PPI (Pixels Per Inch) units and resize the image to 1500x1500 pixels wide/high based on the longest side of the image if the image is larger than 1500 pixels on whatever that longest side is. Image quality is set to 90 as well.

I use this simple Bash script to process images I want to be relatively high resolution yet also be web ready. But you can adjust and tweak that command to suit your needs. The real magic is the `find` logic that will traverse the directory tree and overwrite images in place. And by doing that the creation date is retained and only the modification date is changed on the file.